# How can I resize a QGraphicsTextItem including its text/contents in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, resize, qgraphicstextitem, qgraphicswidget

I made a QGraphicsTextItem and set plain text as its content. After that, I set the QGraphicsTextItem inside the QGraphicsWidget.

My question is, Is it possible to resize the `QGraphicsTextItem` including its text/contents like in this picture:

[image]

This is the video of the resizing that I'm asking for.

[image: Video of Resizing]

If this is possible, how can I apply it to the `QGraphicsTextItem`?

The first picture is the image of the `QGraphicsTextItem` but I have no idea how to implement the resizing in the video.

Things I've tried:

- I tried using the `setTextWidth()` and setting it to 0.5 but it's not working.
- I also tried using `adjustSize()` to the QGraphicsTextItem but it's also not working.

Code to reproduce the issue:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.view = QGraphicsView()

        scene = QGraphicsScene()

        #before resizing
        item = QGraphicsTextItem("Line 1 Line 2 Line 3")
        item.setFlags(QGraphicsWidget.ItemIsSelectable)
        item.setPos(self.view.mapToScene(2, 2))
        scene.addItem(item)

        #after resizing
        item_1 = QGraphicsTextItem("Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3")
        item_1.setFlags(QGraphicsWidget.ItemIsSelectable)
        item_1.setPos(self.view.mapToScene(2, 30))
        scene.addItem(item_1)

        self.view.setScene(scene)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Using `setTextWidth()` is the proper way, but 0.5 doesn't seem a valid value. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante - I'm very sorry for the late response, I've now added the code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Uhm, your code does not reproduce the problem. In fact, it doesn't seem to relate to the question at all: there's no "resizing", and there's no trace of a QGraphicsWidget: you're just adding two QGraphicsTextItem. Have you missed something when copy and pasting your original example?